# Access javascript global variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

Following is my JavaScript. How do I make the variable `success` global so that the changes made in ajax->success are reflected outside?

```
function foo() {  
    var success = false;  
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var code = parseInt($(xml).find("Response").attr("code"), 10);
            switch (code) {
                case 1:
                    success = false;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    success = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    return success;
}
```

Comment: I believe if you are declaring it outside any function , it is a global variable. It will be something like `window.success` !!!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but the variable "success" is placed properly and should work. Besides, if you're returning "success", it means you're using it in a function, making a private variable for that specific function. If you want to make it a global variable, simply put it at the very start of you're script, or just right outside this function.

Comment: This is literally the most asked question in JavaScript SO. It's all in the name: AJAX or **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's the question I was trying to find but just posted the typical comment.

Comment: @elclanrs that was the first question that popped up when I clicked `close > duplicate`

Comment: @RobG `success = !code`. Ian got this right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a callback function that is called in the `success`:

```
function makeCall(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var code = parseInt($(xml).find("Response").attr("code"), 10);
            callback(!code);
        }
    });
}

makeCall(function (success) {
    alert(success);
});
```

This is how asynchronous programming/requests work. Of course, the alternative is to make it a synchronous request, but kind of defeats the purpose.

I condensed the `switch` stuff because you seemed to want the opposite boolean values of `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are after will not work. The Ajax call is asynchronous. Meaning it will return immediately even before the actual GET is fired. So the outer var (which is accessible from inside the success callback, thanks to closures) won't have any value other than the one established before the Ajax call by the time it is returned. Instead you can specify that the Ajax call fire synchronously, by setting async:false along with the other values in the $.ajax, or you can restructure the code to do whatever you wanted to do if the function returned true by putting it inside the success callback.

Comment: I was thinking of upvoting you until I saw you recommend `async:false`

Comment: `async:false` is to `ajax` as `eval` is to `string`?

Comment: @elclanrs no. `eval` merely invites injection attacks and is slow as hell. `async:false` is pure evil ;-)

Comment: I agree, I was just trying to be complete :)